# Are these ZIORepository and Controller for mvc correct?

Tags: model-view-controller, repository

### Repository

namespace AgenziaMatrimoniale.DataAccess {
    public class AgenziaMatrimonialeRepository
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AgenziaMatrimonialeConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

```
    public List<Candidato> FindSimple(int? id, string sesso, string citta)
    {

        List<Candidato> result = new List<Candidato>();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Candidato";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var dbId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]);
                    var dbNome = Convert.ToString(reader["Nome"]);
                    var dbCognome = Convert.ToString(reader["Cognome"]);
                    var dbSesso = Convert.ToString(reader["Sesso"]);
                    var dbCitta = Convert.ToString(reader["Citta"]);
                    var dbProfessione = Convert.ToString(reader["Professione"]);
                    var dbDescrizione = Convert.ToString(reader["Descrizione"]);


                    if (id.HasValue && dbId == id)
                    {
                        AggiungiCandidatoAiRisultati(result, dbId, dbNome, dbCognome, dbSesso, dbCitta, dbProfessione, dbDescrizione);
                    }
                    else if (!id.HasValue 
                        && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sesso) || dbSesso==sesso)
                        && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(citta)|| dbCitta.ToLower().Contains(citta.ToLower())))
                    {
                        AggiungiCandidatoAiRisultati(result, dbId, dbNome, dbCognome, dbSesso, dbCitta, dbProfessione, dbDescrizione);
                    }

                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Errore applicativo: {0}", ex.Message));
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Candidato FindCandidato(int id)
    {
        List<Candidato> candidati = FindSimple(id, null, null);

        if (candidati.Count == 1)
        {
            return candidati[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

### Controller

namespace AgenziaMatrimoniale.Controllers
{
    public class CandidatoController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AgenziaMatrimonialeRepository _repository;

```
    public CandidatoController()
    {
        _repository = new AgenziaMatrimonialeRepository();
    }

    public ActionResult Index(string sesso, string citta)
    {
        List<Candidato> candidati = _repository.FindSimple(null, sesso, citta);

        List<SelectListItem> sessi= new List<SelectListItem> {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Maschio", Value = "M" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Femmina", Value = "F" }
        };

        ViewBag.sesso = sessi;

        return View(candidati);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        Candidato candidato = _repository.FindCandidato(id);
        return View(candidato);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It depends...if you're trying to fill a table with data collected from a DB and possibly filter that data....then you are doing just fine.
You remind me this little piece of code that's just VERY similar.

```
using Prova1.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Prova1.DataAccess
{
    public class ProvaRepository
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StringConnectionName"].ConnectionString;
        public List<Modello> Find(int? id, string filtro1, string filtro2)
        {
            List<Modello> result = new List<Modello>();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM Tabella";

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var dbId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]);
                        var dbCampo1 = Convert.ToString(reader["Campo1"]);
                        var dbCampo2 = Convert.ToString(reader["Campo2"]);
                        var dbCampo3 = Convert.ToString(reader["Campo3"]);
                        Modello modello = new Modello();

                        if (id.HasValue && dbId == id)
                        {
                            AddModello(result, dbId, dbCampo1, dbCampo2, dbCampo3, modello);
                        }
                        else if (!id.HasValue
                            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtro1) || dbCampo1.ToLower().Contains(filtro1.ToLower()))
                            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtro2) || dbCampo2.ToLower().Contains(filtro2.ToLower()))
                            )
                        {
                            AddModello(result, dbId, dbCampo1, dbCampo2, dbCampo3, modello);
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Errore Applicativo {0}: ", ex.Message));
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        private static void AddModello(List<Modello> result, int dbId, string dbCampo1, string dbCampo2, string dbCampo3, Modello modello)
        {
            modello.Id = dbId;
            modello.Campo1 = dbCampo1;
            modello.Campo2 = dbCampo2;
            modello.Campo3 = dbCampo3;
            result.Add(modello);
        }
        public Modello FindDetail(int id)
        {
            List<Modello> modello = Find(id, null, null);
            if (modello.Count == 1)
            {
                return modello[0];
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I forgot the **Controller**

```
using Prova1.DataAccess;
using Prova1.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Prova1.Controllers
{
    public class ProvaController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ProvaRepository _repository;
        public ProvaController()
        {
            _repository = new ProvaRepository();
        }
        // GET: Prova
        public ActionResult Index(string filtro1, string filtro2)
        {
            List<Modello> modelli = _repository.Find(null, filtro1, filtro2);
            return View(modelli);
        }
        public ActionResult Detail(int id)
        {
            Modello modello = _repository.FindDetail(id);
            return View(modello);
        }
    }
}
```